# Which command in Selenium IDE will select value from combobox for automation of website?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am generating automation script using Selenium IDE. My website contains 3 Combo Boxes as 1.Resource Type, 2.Meter Type, 3.Plan
I written following commands and Target values.

```
 Command: Click
    Target://div[@id='Engg_unit']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div/div[2]/span

   Command:KeyDown
   Target:css=input.wijmo-wijcombobox-input
   value:\40

   Command:KeyDown
   Target:css=input.wijmo-wijcombobox-input
   value:\13
```

Its working fine for First Combobox but when i use same command for remaining two its doesn't make any selection.

Which command to use to automate selection for remaining combobox?